# Don't work the clear method in DatePicker when inputted invalid value

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-date-picker

Don't work the clear method in DatePicker when inputted invalid value.
I found mention of this bug in several articles https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1696, but I can't find any solutions.
I thought call "onClearButtonClick" function from js in java code. This function called when click in the clear button inside DatePicker.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/2176 mentions two potential workarounds also there is new [comment](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1696#issuecomment-1028908563) in the original ticket suggesting to call
`datePicker.getElement().executeJs("this.inputElement.value = ''")`
from the Java code to forcefully clear the DatePicker.

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin 14 you can execute js to set the value to null but don't forget to dispatch the change event.

```
document.getElementById('yourdatepicker').value = null;
document.getElementById('yourdatepicker').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```